# Need help solving iterativelly a set of transcendental equations with NIntegrate

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I have two sets of equations:

$q = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int dz~ e^{-z^2/2}F(q,\phi;z,\beta,\Delta, J) $

$\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\int dz~ e^{-z^2/2}G(q,\phi;z,\beta, \Delta, J) $

As you may see they are self-consistent equations, the main problem is that the expressions for $F$ and $G$ quite involved, so the integration over $z$ can only be achieved by a numerical integration.

My goal is to these self-consistent equations for several values of the parameters $\Delta$ and $\beta$, then plot $x(\beta)$ for different values of $\Delta$. The problems I'm proceeding in the following way:

The functions $F$ and $G$ are actually fractions with a common denominator I define as

```
Den[\[CapitalDelta]_, J_, \[Beta]_, q_, \[Phi]_, z_] = 
 (1/\[CapitalDelta])*Integrate[Exp[(-2^(-1))*(q - \[Phi])*\[Beta]^2*J^2*t^2]*
    Cosh[\[Beta]*J*Sqrt[q]*z*t], {t, 1 - \[CapitalDelta]/2, 1 + \[CapitalDelta]/2}]
```

Then we comput the full functions $F$ and $G$, defined as fractionq and fraction$\phi$ in the latex code

```
fractionq[\[CapitalDelta]_, J_, \[Beta]_, q_, \[Phi]_] = 1/\[CapitalDelta]*Integrate[Exp[-1/2 (q-\[Phi]) \[Beta]^2 J^2 t^2] (t^2 Cosh[\[Beta] J Sqrt[q] z t]- z t /(\[Beta] J Sqrt[q])Sinh[\[Beta] J Sqrt[q]z t]),{t, 1-\[CapitalDelta]/2,1+\[CapitalDelta]/2}]/Den[\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi], z]
fraction\[Phi][\[CapitalDelta]_, J_, \[Beta]_, q_, \[Phi]_] = 1/\[CapitalDelta]*Integrate[Exp[-1/2 (q-\[Phi]) \[Beta]^2 J^2 t^2] t^2 Cosh[\[Beta] J Sqrt[q] z t],{t, 1-\[CapitalDelta]/2,1+\[CapitalDelta]/2}]/Den[\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi], z]
```

We then prepare the HoldForm of the numerical integration over $z$

```
RHSq[\[CapitalDelta]_, J_, \[Beta]_, q_, \[Phi]_]:= NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-1/2 z^2] fractionq[\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi]], {z, -Infinity, Infinity},
 PrecisionGoal->4, WorkingPrecision->10, AccuracyGoal->10, MinRecursion->2]
RHS\[Phi][\[CapitalDelta]_, J_, \[Beta]_, q_, \[Phi]_]:= NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-1/2 z^2] fraction\[Phi][\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi]], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
PrecisionGoal->4, WorkingPrecision->10, AccuracyGoal->10, MinRecursion->2]
```

And finally we defined the ordered pair {RHSq, RHS$\phi$} to which we are going to apply a function (either FixedPoint, Nest, NestWhile) in order to solve iteratively for several values of $\beta$ and $\Delta$.

```
newpairs[\[CapitalDelta]_, J_, \[Beta]_][{q_, \[Phi]_}]:={RHSq[\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi]], RHS\[Phi][\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi]]}

Table[FixedPoint[newpairs[0.2, 1, \[Beta]],{1.5,1}],{\[Beta],\[Beta]list}]
```

where $\beta$list is just a list of the different values of $\beta$ I want to generate.

```
TemperatureList = Table[i, {i, 0.0002, 2.0002, 0.02}]
\[Beta]list = 1/TemperatureList
```

The following are the error outputs displayed while running this routine:

NIntegrate::inumri "The integrand **...** has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all 
sampling points in the region with boundaries 
{{-[Infinity],-3.000000000}}"

General::stop "Further output of NIntegrate::inumri will be suppressed during this 
calculation"

NIntegrate::write "tag Times in -z is Protected"

several times

Comment: Welcome to [Mathematica.SE]!  Please edit your question to include the code you've come up with so far;  it will be much easier for users to give you useful advice if they know the details of your problem, particularly the functions $F$ and $G$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Sorry this is my first post, do you think is better in this way or can I make it more readable?

Comment: That's much more answerable now, but it throws an error on my system because it doesn't include a definition of `βlist`.  Can you edit your question to include it?

Comment: Yeah! sorry, it's done

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use `FixedPoint` rather than `FindRoot`?  On my five-year-old MacBook, `FindRoot` returns a root of the equation `newpairs[0.2, 1, 1][{q, \[Phi]}] == {q, \[Phi]}` (i.e., $\beta = 1$) in a little over one minute, which seems like a reasonable time frame if you want to do 100 $\beta$ values.  `FixedPoint` takes longer (it's been running for five minutes so far without an output), but you may have some particular reason that you need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be made to work by one major change and a couple of smaller changes.

- `FindRoot` is generally more efficient than `FixedPoint` for finding roots of equations.  Unless `FixedPoint` is necessary for the particular physical situation you're trying to model (renormalization flows?), I would recommend you use `FindRoot` instead.
- Many of the errors in your code are caused by calls to `NIntegrate` with symbolic integrands, rather than integrands that evaluate to a particular number when provided with an input value in the integration range.  This can be avoided by defining the input slots with `PatternTest`s:

  ```
  fractionq[\[CapitalDelta]_?NumericQ, J_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ, \[Phi]_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] 
     := (* long expression including NIntegrate *)
  ```

  This syntax means that the function (and by extension, `NIntegrate`) will only be called when all of the arguments provided are numerical expressions;  otherwise, it will be returned unevaluated.
- To do this input sanitization properly, the argument `z` should be an argument to the integrand functions `fractionq` and  `fraction\[Phi]`.

With these modifications, Mathematica returns a result for `q` and `\[Phi]` in 20–140 seconds (on my five-year-old Macbook Pro) for values of $\beta$ between 0.5 and 2, with lower $\beta$ taking longer.  This would make it feasible to run this code for the 100 data points that you want;  your result would be ready in a few hours.

Further speed-ups could be obtained by using `ParallelTable` (allowing your computer to calculate several data points at once);  using an "annealing" process where the results for one value of `\[Beta]` are used as initial guesses for the next value of `\[Beta]` (reducing the number of steps `FindRoot` has to make before getting convergence);  and making compiled versions of the integrand functions.

---

#### Modified code:

```
fractionq[\[CapitalDelta]_?NumericQ, J_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, 
  q_?NumericQ, \[Phi]_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := 
 1/\[CapitalDelta]*
  NIntegrate[
    Exp[-1/
        2 (q - \[Phi]) \[Beta]^2 J^2 t^2] (t^2 Cosh[\[Beta] J Sqrt[
           q] z t] - 
       z t/(\[Beta] J Sqrt[q]) Sinh[\[Beta] J Sqrt[q] z t]), {t, 
     1 - \[CapitalDelta]/2, 1 + \[CapitalDelta]/2}]/
   Den[\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi], z]

fraction\[Phi][\[CapitalDelta]_?NumericQ, 
  J_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ, \[Phi]_?NumericQ, 
  z_?NumericQ] := 
 1/\[CapitalDelta]*
  NIntegrate[
    Exp[-1/2 (q - \[Phi]) \[Beta]^2 J^2 t^2] t^2 Cosh[\[Beta] J Sqrt[
        q] z t], {t, 1 - \[CapitalDelta]/2, 1 + \[CapitalDelta]/2}]/
   Den[\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi], z]

RHSq[\[CapitalDelta]_?NumericQ, J_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, 
  q_?NumericQ, \[Phi]_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-1/2 z^2] fractionq[\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], 
    q, \[Phi], z], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10, MinRecursion -> 2]

RHS\[Phi][\[CapitalDelta]_?NumericQ, J_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ,     
  q_?NumericQ, \[Phi]_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[
  1/Sqrt[2 Pi] Exp[-1/2 z^2] fraction\[Phi][\[CapitalDelta], 
    J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi], z], {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  PrecisionGoal -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 10, 
  MinRecursion -> 2]

newpairs[\[CapitalDelta]_, 
   J_, \[Beta]_][{q_?NumericQ, \[Phi]_?
    NumericQ}] := {RHSq[\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi]], 
  RHS\[Phi][\[CapitalDelta], J, \[Beta], q, \[Phi]]}

\[Beta] = 1.;
FindRoot[newpairs[0.2, 1, \[Beta]][{q, \[Phi]}] == {q, \[Phi]}, {{q, 1}, {\[Phi], 1.5}}]

(* {q -> 0.0101124, \[Phi] -> 1.01008} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! it seems to be working way better, just that for some values of $\beta$, for example 5000 or even 50, it outputs the following error

```Wolfram

NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand 0.398942 E^(-0.5 z^2) fractionq[0.2,1.,5000.,0.,0.,z] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-\[Infinity],-3.000000000}}.
```

I imagine I can correct this error by playing with the NIntegrate parameters right?, which parameters are better to tune in this case?

Comment: @GreivinAlfaro:  That I'm not sure about.  I would take a look at what the integrand is actually doing in those cases and perhaps look at truncating the range of integration based on that.  Also, are you still using `FixedPoint` for some reason?  I only got that error when I tried using `FixedPoint`, as in your original code.  Using `FindRoot`, as in my modified code, doesn't throw that error at all.

Comment: My guess is that the problem comes from the fact that your integrands are of the form $e^{-\beta^2 k} \cosh (\beta z l)$, where $k$ and $l$ are combinations of other constants.  These could easily evaluate to something of the form $0 \times \infty$ internally when Mathematica plugs in real numbers.